# How to display an attachment thumbnail in view in xpages

Tags: view, xpages, attachment

I've searched for an answer but am not finding what I need.  I have an attachment inside of a Notes document that I want to display in a view control as a thumbnail.

1. Do I simply put @AttachmentNames in the view column formula?
2. How do I tell the column in the view control to display a thumbnail?
3. Do I need a separate thumbnail "image" in my doc or can it create one from the file attached in the Notes document?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I know about this started from this blog post:

http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM

For Posterity here are the 2 key functions (SSJS) :

```
function getAttachmentURL(docID:java.lang.String, attachmentName:java.lang.String) {
    var base = getBaseURL();
    var middle = "/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment";
    if (base.substr(0,4) == "/xsp") {
        middle += base.substr(4);
    } else {
        middle += base;
    }
    var result = base + middle + "/" + docID + "/$File/" + attachmentName + "?Open";
    return result;
}

function getBaseURL() {
    var curURL = context.getUrl();
    var curAdr = curURL.getAddress();
    var rel = curURL.getSiteRelativeAddress(context);
    var step1 = curAdr.substr(0,curAdr.indexOf(rel));

    // Now cut off the http
    var step2 = step1.substr(step1.indexOf("//")+2);
    var result = step2.substr(step2.indexOf("/"));
    return result;

   }
```

What you do is you're basically going to create an old fashioned non xpages - meaning classic domino link.  You want something like :

http(s)://[yourserver]/[application.nsf]/[viewname|0]/[UNID| ViewKey]/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open

Then that link you can put in an XPages image control or whatever.  I don't use view panels but there is a way to get the image in there.  You might need to make a blank view column and drop in an image control.  I forget exactly.  It's been blogged about I'm sure.  So Google might help there.

I would avoid @AttachmentNames..  Honestly I would highly recommend avoiding ALL @formulas in XPages.  I'm sure there's a way to get AttachmentNames via the Domino Object model.  Use that instead.  It'll help you in the future.

as for the thumbnail...  You might want one...  If someone attaches a 2MB Image...  sure the browser can render that to any size you want... but it first would need to download the whole 2MB!  ouch.  So for speed if you already have a thumbnail that would be nicer.  In theory you could have the server create a thumbnail on the fly...  But i did that once..  and it got really ugly really quick if say you wanted to have a page with 30 pictures or more and each time it hits the server is resizing the images down to a thumbnail.

What I did..  is I made a more involved attachment system.  I never store the images in key document.  I put them in another database with shared keys.  Actually I put them in 3 databases.  So when someone uploads an image...  I store it in "original.nsf".  Then I resize it to a "large.nsf" and "small.nsf"  So I can get close to the size I need when I need it.

I've still not made a video of all this yet.  But I do have a semi-working project with code examples and such on bitbucket.  https://bitbucket.org/leedy/filevault

Comment: David, thank you so much for this information.  I'm going to sift through and try and fit it into my app.  Question: my current design for the images is through native Notes and is using a Rich Text field to attach the image.  You mentioned uploading files.  The web part of this app is only for certain people in the company and I didn't want to re-program everything in xPages because I'm a contractor for this company.  My mindset has not completely changed over to xPages.  The way I have it will work, right?

Comment: if you're not uploading via xpages and just viewing it doesn't matter.  no difference.  At the end of the day you're getting to the image of the document via a classic domino url. No xpages is involved there.  You're just taking that link and then displaying it with anything - in this case it's an xpages control.  So no - you do not need to upload through xpages to make this work.